# How correctly send time to Alexa using SSML?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, ssml

I am trying to make SSML like this: `$ 11:20 Am`

but Alexa speaks: `"Dollar eleven colon twenty AM"`.

If I remove `$`, Alexa will speak: `"Dollar eleven twenty AM"`.

What is wrong with symbol `$` and how to solve it?

Comment: Could you provide some code? Also are you sure, that when you remove `$`, Alexa speaks `"Dollar (...)"`?

Comment: what is your expected speech output?